Recurring MySQL insertion doesn't seem to work
I'm currently working on a webbased library as a project. Currently, the code performs what it needs to do except when it encounters a directory, instead of it running the function again it instead does nothing.
function insertToTable($dire){
    include "./modular/filesLogic.php";
    $scanf = scandir($dire);
    unset($scanf[array_search('.', $scanf, true)]);
    unset($scanf[array_search('..', $scanf, true)]);
        
    for($s = 2; $s<count($scanf); $s++){
        $iextension = pathinfo($scanf[$s], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $inamewoext = pathinfo($scanf[$s], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $datec = date("Y-m-d");
        $sze = filesize($dire."/".$scanf[$s]);

        $seql = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE name='$inamewoext'";
        $resi = mysqli_query($conn, $seql);
            
        if(is_dir($scanf[$s])){
            $iextension = "dir";
            insertToTable($scanf[$s]);
        }

        if(mysqli_num_rows($resi) <= 0){
            $seeql = "INSERT INTO files (name, ftype, dateup, size, downloads, dirGroup) VALUES ('$inamewoext', '$iextension', '$datec', $sze, 0, '$dire')";
            $ress = mysqli_query($conn, $seeql);
        }
    }
}
insertToTable("uploads");


Welcome to SO.  What is in filesLogic.php?  What is the point of the $iextension = "dir"; when you encounter a directory?  Also, be careful with terminology, "MySQL injection" means something very different to what you are asking about.

filesLogic.php contains the code for the connection ($conn) to my database. It includes the code for uploading and downloading files to and from the database. I wanted to see if it will record $iextension as "dir" in my database when it encounters a directory. I see, I'm sorry I'll reword the title thanks @Don'tPanic

You might need to use something like $dire . '/' . $scanf[$s], for is_dir() and insertToTable(). The issue is that you need to supply the correct whole directory path to check and scan.

Including the db connection in a recursive function without logic to test whether or not it has already been included seems wasteful. Why use $s = 2 in the for loop - is that to negate the . and .. entries?

My index.php includes the db connection but for some reason when I make a php function the connections don't seem to work that's why I included the db connection on all of my functions. Yes, the $s = 2 is for negating the . and .. entries. I thought that would be better since although they got unset they still are included when I insert the files into the database. @ProfessorAbronsius

That's because you use $conn inside a function, in local scope, whereas $conn is defined in the global scope of filesLogic.php. When you include filesLogic.php outside the function, you could add $conn as an argument to the function (preferred) or add global $conn; inside the function. See: Variable scope.

Thanks @KIKOSoftware, I'll edit these parts of my code in the future. About the $dire . '/' . $scanf[$s] it still doesn't seem to work. I keep adding files in the "uploads" folder and it inserts it into the database so I really think it's because of either the placement of my function call or the variable I inserted into it.

Your $s = 2 approach means the last two elements of your $scanf array will not get processed as the array is now two elements shorter but the first index is 2. Either switch to using foreach to iterate over the array or use continue to skip . and ...

You're right, I didn't notice that. Thanks @user1191247. Would you happen to know how to accurately convert a for loop into a foreach loop in PHP?

Just change for($s = 2; $s<count($scanf); $s++){ to foreach($scanf as $file){ and then use $file instead of $scanf[$s].

You might consider using a recursiveIterator in preference to a recursive function perhaps - it will easily navigate through your folder hierarchy and allow access to the filename/filepath. I put together a function that uses a recursiveIterator that should do what you are hoping to do. The DB connection is accessed within the function after declaring it as global but you could alternatively add it as a second named parameter to the insertTable function.
Note that the insert SQL still adds both a date and a default download where these could (and probably should) simply be default values assigned to the columns in the db itself - where the dateup could be a timestamp (using current_timestamp)
function insertToTable( $dir=false ){
    if( !realpath( $dir ) )return false;
    
    # declare global variable (or include as a function parameter)
    global $conn;
    
    # basic sql cmds for use in "prepared statements"
    $sql=(object)array(
        'select'=>'SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `name`=?',
        'insert'=>'INSERT INTO `files` ( `name`, `ftype`, `dateup`, `size`, `downloads`, `dirGroup` ) VALUES (?,?,now(),?,0,?)'
    );
    # create the prepared statements
    $stmts=(object)array(
        'select'=>$conn->prepare($sql->select),
        'insert'=>$conn->prepare($sql->insert)
    );
    # bind placeholders to variables (variables created later)
    $stmts->select->bind_param('s',$name);
    $stmts->insert->bind_param('ssss',$name,$type,$size,$folder);
    
    # counter variable for info
    $counter=0;

    # create the recursiveIterators & scan the directory
    $dirItr=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::KEY_AS_PATHNAME );
    $recItr=new RecursiveIteratorIterator( $dirItr, RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST );

    # iterate through scan results
    foreach( $recItr as $obj => $entity ) {
        # process files only
        if( $entity->isFile() ){
            $type  = pathinfo( $entity->getPathName(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
            $name  = pathinfo( $entity->getPathName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME );
            $folder= realpath( pathinfo( $entity->getPathName(), PATHINFO_DIRNAME ) );
            $size=filesize( $entity->getPathName() );
            
            # query db to see if file already exists
            $stmts->select->execute();
            $stmts->select->store_result();
            
            # If file does not exist in db, add it.
            if( $stmts->select->num_rows==0 ){
                $stmts->insert->execute();
                $counter++;
                printf('Adding: %s to db<br>',$name);
            }
            $stmts->select->free_result();
        }
    }
    # close statement objects
    $stmts->select->close();
    $stmts->insert->close();
    
    # leave db open if other tasks are to follow
    # otherwise call $conn->close() and return.
    return $counter ? sprintf('Scan finished: %d files processed', $counter ) : 'Scan completed: No new files added';
}



$dir=__DIR__ . '/uploads';

print insertToTable( $dir );


Thanks for this, looking at this code really reminds me of how much I still don't know about PHP.

I find the whitespacing in this snippet to be unusual.

@mickmackusa ? in what way?

I haven't noticed you using inconsistent spacing previously.  Have you cobbled this answer together using parts of code from different authors?  I don't recall you using so many AI-looking inline comments either.

@mickmackusa - absolutely NOT. This is 100% all my own code and I NEVER use AI to cobble together answers. Quite frankly I find that comment quite insulting and certainly not at all helpful. There are inconsistencies in the spacing perhaps but that is due wholly to my negligence in formatting them all the same.

I'm not sure why you are  insulted by my observations.  You see what I see, right?  This isn't an attack -- it is an observation of an unexpected scripting style in a Professor Abronsius post.  I've not flagged this post for any reason.  The realpath line has excessive spacing (like a Wordpress script), then $stmts declarations and method calls have no spacing at all. My comment at no point asserted that your answer was AI-generated; I said that the inline commenting looked styled like how many explained AI scripts look.
